# Is it possible to use descriptive statistics to make conclusion about "differences"?

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, differences

Here is the question that bothers me for a long time. I used an example to describe my question.

For example, if I asked the same participants to answer the two questions:

Q1) do you think that other students have cheated at least once in college? yes/no

Q2) do you think that you cheated at least once in college? yes/no

The result (n = 100) shows:

| Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| Yes: 80% | Yes: 20% |
| No: 20% | No: 80% |

Can I make the conclusion like:

> "The results show that what participants think about others are
> different from what they think about themselves"  ?

If not, what statistical test should I use to see if there is a difference between what participants think about others are different than themselves?

I thought about Chi-Square, but the participants are the same. I found that McNemar's test may be a more suitable one because McNemar's test is for the sample participants. However, McNemar's test is used to compare before and after, which is not suitable to apply to my case.

I was wondering if anyone can let me know what statistical test is suitable for this case? Are inferential statistics needed? Or what conclusion I can make based on the data? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your conclusion is limited to "participants."  That requires only a description of their responses and statistical testing would be superfluous and misleading.  Are you perhaps hoping to draw conclusions about a wider population than those who responded to the survey?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! No, I just found that from the data I collected, it seems like there is a gap between what participants think about themselves versus others, so I hope that future research can investigate whether there is a gap. But what inferential test should I conduct to be able to make the conclusion that "The results show that what participants think about others are different from what they think about themselves"